# add a Row id to jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello i'm trying to add

why i'm doing this?

because every time i use the this code on my result page using this code below

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
```

the popup appear 16 times as there is 16 result

here is the code

```
    <a href="#0" onclick="$('.cd-popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>
').addClass('is-visible');"  class="cd-popup-trigger">View Pop-up</a>

<div id="popup" class="cd-popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"  role="alert">

    <div class="cd-popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>-container" >
        <ul class="cd-buttons">
<p>your name is   <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></p>



        </ul>
        <a href="#0" onclick="$('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });" class="cd-popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>-close img-replace">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open popup
    $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    //close popup

    //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
});
```

css

```
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
  background: #b6bece;
  border-radius: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #c5ccd8;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

i got 2 solutions on my head
 first is adding row numbers to the css which is going to be alot of classes cd-container_1 to cd-container_1000 or more 
second is adding the css to the div tags via style="" which is gonna be more useful but not gonna work too any suggestions

Comment: would you like to explain more ?

Comment: ok john i have a php code which is 
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
<button onclick='$("#popup_<?php echo $row["id"];?>").fadeIn();'>click</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
<div class="overlay"> </div>
    <div class="box">
        <span>x</span>
    </div>
</div>


                            ?>


<?php
}}

this is working fine but when i add the codepin script it doesn't work probably because the popup got duplicated 16times as there is 16 mysql result

Comment: Ahmed, I guess John was asking what do you mean by: "add a row id to class so i can distinguish between them"... I've [answered below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36008776/1326147) assuming that you just wanted to use the `$row["id"]` in the HTML `class` attribute instead of using it in the `id` attribute. Is that what you want? If not, you need to provide more explanations...

Comment: kindly check my edit

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to distinguish classes, then you just need to pass your `echo` to those classes and use `.` instead of `#` in the jQuery selector:

```
<button onclick='$(".popup_<?php echo $row["id"];?>").fadeIn();'>click</button>

<div class="popup_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
```

You may not need the id in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the fallowing structure for each popup:

```
<button class="trigger-popup">click</button>
<div class="popup">
<div class="overlay"> </div>
    <div class="box">
        <span>x</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

js should look like:

```
$('.trigger-popup').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4jk9hq1/